# USB 3.0 hard drive docking station does not work unless using USB 2.0 port

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I have a Sharkoon SATA QuickPort with USB 3.0 connection (http://www.sharkoon.com/?q=en/content/sata-quickport-xt-usb30-v2). Whenever I connect this device to a USB 3.0 port on my computer with a hard drive in the QuickPort. The hard drive isn't recognized in Windows.

When I try to reboot my computer, it hangs on the shutting down screen unless I power off the QuickPort (then my computer shuts down immediately). When it starts booting I put the power back on on the QuickPort, and the boot process hangs too. When I again power it off my computer boots up instantly.

When I connect the same QuickPort a USB 2.0 port on the motherboard, none of this happens and I can happily do whatever I want (mainly creating backup images of customer hard drives).

When I plug in a regular USB 3.0 stick into that same USB 3.0 port on my motherboard I can use it just fine, so I don't think there is a driver problem.

It has always been like this since I'm using Windows 8 so I'm guessing it's some OS setting.

Comment: No;  It actually sounds like a hardware incompatibility.

Comment: Incompatibility between hardware and OS, hardware <> motherboard,...?

Comment: My response is based on the following assumptions. 1) The problem always existed. 2) You have not tried other HDDs with the Sharkoon 3) You understand the device itself is a **USB 2.0** device.  [The product you linked to is a USB 2.0 only device.](http://www.sharkoon.com/sites/default/files/ddblock/nid-1733/images/datasheet_en_pdf_53188.pdf)

Comment: 1), The problem has always existed on Windows 8, not on Windows 7 on the exact same computer (dual boot).
2) I have tried numerous hard drives in the docking station, always same result
3) Sorry, wrong link, updated question.

Comment: How many USB devices do you have installed at any given time?

Comment: At the moment 3: receiver for keyboard/mouse, card reader, and the docking station.